# Include jQuery in karma config

Tags: jquery, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to include jQuery to my karma config file but I am unable to make it work. I tried adding it to the files array like this

```
files: [
'node_modules/jquery/src/*.js',
'node_modules/jquery/src/**/*.js'
...]
```

Every time I try and run the tests I get

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: define at node_modules/jquery/src/ajax.js:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, but to include jQuery in my karma testing config I added the cdn url for jQuery as so

```
files: [
  'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js',
  ...]
```